# Como puedo obtener la ubicacion desde la que se esta ejecutando mi programa? - C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Quisiera saber cómo puedo obtener la ubicación desde la que se esta ejecutando mi programa.

Por ejemplo: yo creé un editor de texto y quiero que si yo pongo mi programa para iniciar por defecto en un archivo txt, que el programa al abrirlo me diga la dirección donde se encuentra ese archivo txt .

Para poner por defecto el programa lo doy click derecho al archivo de texto y en las propiedades le cambio el programa con el que se abre el txt. Pero cuando logré hacer o de que el programa me diga la ubicación de ese txt haré todo este proceso ejecutando un código en batch para que cambie el programa por el que se abren por defecto los programas con esta extensión.

Comment: No queda muy clara la pregunta. Si con ubicación te refieres al *path* la carpeta y nombre del archivo ejecutable o a otra cosa. Si te refieres al *path*, es al que está corriendo (o sea el lugar donde probablemente hayas instalado el programa) o si te refieres al archivo que estás abriendo (o el que disparó la ejecución de tu programa).

Comment: Tampoco parece muy buena idea (es más parece un poco invasivo) cambiar los valores por defecto al abrir un programa

Comment: obviamente se pediría permiso antes de cambiar el valor por defecto del programa, seria una opción habilitable. Y lo que estoy intentando buscar es la forma de encontrar el path del archivo txt desde donde se esta abriendo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes saber cual es la ruta en la cual se está ejecutando el contexto de la aplicación mirando el `BaseDirectory` del `AppDomain`.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Lo que comentas del archvo `.txt` no te lo entendí muy bien, pero si está en el mismo directorio que el `.exe` de la aplicación, el caso sería el mismo.

De no ser así, para abrirlo necesitas el path de antemano, por lo que no tengo muy claro cual sería el caso que necesitas controlar más allá del `BaseDirectory`.

---

EDITADO: 
En base a los comentarios, añado esta otra respuesta para recuperar el path del fichero.

Cuando creas una asociación de ficheros en Windows, básicamente lo que hace es enviarlo como argumento por línea de comandos.

Para recuperarlo, simplemente tienes que recuperar ese argumento

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IList<string> ficheros = new List<string>();
    foreach (string fichero in args)
    {
        ficheros.Add(fichero);
    }
}
```

Con ese código en el main principal lo que hacemos es recuperar todos los argumentos que se le pasan a nuestro ejecutable (presumiblemente rutas de ficheros) y rellenar una lista con dichos parámetros.

Si sólo quisieras abrir un fichero cada vez y no des soporte a abrir varios ficheros de una vez, simplemente necesitarías recuperar el primer parámetro:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fichero = null;
    if(args.Length > 0)
    {
        fichero = args[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: frikinside Mi problema es que yo necesito la ubicación del txt no del exe no se si se me entiende osea: Si pongo un archivo txt para que se abra por defecto con mi programa al abrirlo necesito que el programa detecte donde se encuentra ese txt para poder utilizar la dirección del txt

Comment: @JoaquinGiordano Ok, de acuerdo, pero como "pones un archivo txt para que se abra por defecto"? Si nos pudieses decir como haces esa operación te podríamos decir como recuperar la ruta de ese fichero. Donde lo abres? Como lo abres? Ese tipo de información es necesaria para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: frikinside para poner por defecto el programa lo doy click derecho al archivo de texto y en las propiedades le cambio el programa con el que se abre el txt. Pero cuando logre hacer o de que el programa me diga la ubicación de ese txt hare todo este proceso ejecutando un código en batch para que cambie el programa por el que se abren por defecto los programas con esta extension

Comment: @JoaquinGiordano he añadido una actualización que creo que encaja mejor con lo que preguntabas.

Comment: frikinside no logro entender tu código y te comento que que no estamos hablando de una aplicación de consola y es una aplicación en c# de visual studio lo comento por si acaso

Comment: @JoaquinGiordano Dejando de lado que una aplicación de consola no deja de ser también una aplicación en c# de visual studio como dices, (imagino que te refieras a WindowsForms). El caso es el mismo, sendos tipos de proyectos deben de tener una clase `Program` con un método `Main` donde poder aplicar un código semejante al que te pongo de ejemplo. Esa era la parte que no entendías o había algo más que necesitase de una explicación más extendida?

Comment: frikinside muchas gracias.Me ayudaste con una cosa que llevo mucho tiempo buscando